# Interaction Term Insignificant but Composite Variable Significant

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, composite, centering

I have 4 latent variables each with 3-7 indicators.  I created a composite for each variable by summing the data and then mean-centering (variables have some collinearity issues, highly related).  Thus I have Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4.

I then wanted to create a master composite of all four variables.  I thus summed all the individual indicators and mean-centered the total, for Var1234.

I'm trying to test the theory of complementarity in which these four variables are greater together than individually (i.e. var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 = 4 ... but Var1234 >4)

I ran two linear regressions.
MODEL 1: All the individual indicators + Individual interaction terms + 4 way interaction term = DV
MODEL 2: Var1234 = DV

In the 2nd model Var1234 is significant, however in the 1st model the 4 way interaction term is insignificant.  I believe this is a problem, but I am not sure.  Is it related to the way I created my composite variables, or the fact that there is a 2nd order variable that is a composite of other composites?

Is there a way to explain why a 4 way interaction term is insignificant when the composite of those 4 terms IS significant?

Comment: (1) Could you please tell us what you mean by "DV"? In this context most of us would read "dependent variable," but then it makes no sense to say it is "significant." (2) What do you mean by "interaction"? I suspect you intend that to refer to the "composites" you have created, but ordinarily in a regression context an "interaction" refers to a *product* of one or more independent variables. As a result of these issues, I'm unsure what you are asking and suspect others may be equally puzzled.

Comment: Sure.. Ill clarify!

Comment: I have a dependent variable which is the same for both linear regression models.  In model 1 my IVs include all of the direct relationships of 4 composite variables I created (var1-var4) in addition to two-way interactions between all of those variables (6 total, var1xvar2, var1xvar3, var1xvar4, var2xvar3 ... etc) AND a 4 way interaction term (var1xvar2xvar3xvar4).  Model 2 simply includes the composite I created (var1234).  I created 5 composite variables total - one for EACH variable (var1, var2, var3, var4) in addition to a 2nd order factor containing ALL 4.

Comment: In model 2 the composite variable (to create I summed all 21 of the indicators from var1-var4 and mean-centered) is significant.  However in model 1 the four way interaction term (var1xvar2var3xvar4) is NOT significant.  I believe it should be and am worried that I am calculating these composite variables incorrectly.  Sorry for the confusion with my original post!